# Using python ldap3, getting memberof by userid

Tags: python, ldap3, memberof

Can someone help me out with a search for memberof by `cn = 'userid'` ?

this is what I have so far:

```
c.search( search_base='DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=company,DC=com',
            search_filter='(CN=userid)',
            search_scope='SUBTREE',
            attributes=['memberOf'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c.search(search_base='DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=company,DC=com',
         search_filter=('(sAMAccountName={0})').format(usrname),
         search_scope=SUBTREE,
         attributes=['cn', 'displayName', 'mail','member'])
```

The above worked for me.

Also you can refer this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366499/ldap3-python-search-members-of-a-group-and-retrieve-their-samacountname-active) as well. Good luck.