# ldap search_filter escape specific charter

Tags: python, ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

I retrieve members of a group and their sAMAccountName (NT Accounts) I run the following code takes from: [ldap3 python search members of a group and retrieve their sAMAcountName (Active Directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366499/)

I'm getting user name as output but after few responses I'm getting the error bellow:

> ldap_conn.search(search_base='DC=DOMAIN,DC=com',search_filter=f'(distinguishedName={member})',attributes=['sAMAccountName']) File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py",
> line 838, in search request = search_operation(search_base, File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldap3/operation/search.py",
> line 371, in search_operation request['filter'] =
> compile_filter(parse_filter(search_filter, schema, auto_escape,
> auto_encode, validator, check_names).elements[0]) # parse the
> searchFilter string and compile it starting from the root node File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldap3/operation/search.py",
> line 214, in parse_filter raise LDAPInvalidFilterError('malformed
> filter') ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidFilterError: malformed
> filter

it failed once try to retrieve user who have ( ) , ? , # , é  charters in CN, how can escape to avoid from malformed filter error ?

```
base = "CN=mygroup,OU=Security Group,OU=Resources,OU=Global,DC=Domain,DC=com"
ldap_conn.search(search_base = base,search_filter = '(objectClass=group)',search_scope='SUBTREE',attributes = ['member'])

for entry in ldap_conn.entries:
    for member in entry.member.values:
        ldap_conn.search(search_base='OU=Global,DC=Domain,DC=com',search_filter=f'(distinguishedName={member})',attributes=['sAMAccountName'])
        user_sAMAccountName = ldap_conn.entries[0].sAMAccountName.values
        print(user_sAMAccountName)
```

Comment: You need to use [`ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars()`](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/reference/ldap-filter.html). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805523/2529954) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the LDAP client module (you seem to be using `ldap3`):

- For `ldap3`, use `ldap3.utils.conv.escape_filter_chars(member)`.
- For `python-ldap`, use `ldap.filter.escape_filter_chars(member)`.